# Form fields are invisible after running app

Tags: powerapps

When building a screen with a form with 2 fields, after running the app the fields are gone, why?

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The data source for this EditForm screen is an Excel table that contains one record (demo). See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When an Edit Form is played or previewed and it has no data in the datasource then it shows the message "No item to display".  If you had a Gallery control bound to the same datasource, you would also see that it is empty.

You can allow the form to create a new record by having a button with OnSelect="NewForm()" and then the edit fields will be shown.

Comment: Thank you, but the data source for this EditForm screen is an Excel table that contains one record (demo). See my edit above.